# How do I reinstall old Mahjong?

Tags: games

I had to reinstall Ubuntu and my favorite Mahjong is no longer listed in games to be downloaded.Can I readd as I did, with andrew.46 help, with SDL Ball?

Comment: Is that question answered now or can we still help?

Comment: hello, thanks for continuing support.  Not good. Got long list and tried to pick out the mahjong i liked, tried to activate and the end result was it was not recognized?  no progress! thanks for asking.

Comment: Just enter the last command from my post. After the installation finished start it from terminal via entering 'mahjongg'

Answer (score 1):

Please open up a terminal and ....

**Update your package index**

```
sudo apt update
```

**Search for packages containing a string**

```
apt search mahjongg
```

As a result you should get a list of all packages which name or description match your searchstring (here: mahjongg)

**Install packages by name**

```
sudo apt install mahjongg
```

This will install the package mahjongg and all its needed dependencies.

**In Short**

In this example you would need only the last command (edit: and possibly the first) - as we already know the name of the package. I added the other 2 commands to offer some more information and help you in general.

Comment: thank you but more help needed. when i try to type m password the cursor doesen't move?

Comment: Just enter your password and confirm by pressing Enter

Comment: The cursor in the password prompt is supposed to "not move"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mahjongg
```

Type in your password as needed.

Comment: thank you but when i try to enter my password the cursor doesn't move? Need more instruction please.

Comment: The cursor doesn't move  - that's a security feature so that not only can people not see the characters that you are typing, they can't see what number of characters you're typing.  It's just a little bit more secure - someone could listen to tell how many keys you're hitting or whatever, but that's why it is that way from my understanding.

Comment: @JonngInbrasil, don't know if you've gotten this working yet, but if you haven't, just type your password in and type enter.